# DirectX 11 C2661 & C2664 errors constructing SpriteBatch / SpriteFont

Tags: c++, directx11

**I keep having these two errors:**

[image]

> - Error C2664 'DirectX::SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch(const DirectX::SpriteBatch &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'ID3D11DeviceContext *' to 'DirectX::SpriteBatch &&' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory    2068
> - Error C2661 'DirectX::SpriteFont::SpriteFont': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory 2068

I used this source,
https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteFont

```
std::unique_ptr<SpriteBatch> spriteBatch;
std::unique_ptr<SpriteFont> spriteFont;

spriteBatch = std::make_unique<SpriteBatch>(deviceContext);
spriteFont = std::make_unique<SpriteFont>(device, L"myfile.spritefont");

spriteBatch->Begin();
spriteFont->DrawString(spriteBatch.get(), L"Hello, world!", XMFLOAT2(x, y));
spriteBatch->End();
```

I tried wrapping my: `ID3D11Device` & `ID3D11DeviceContext` with `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<>`, but still throws error. Seems there's some issue with the `<memory>`.

**I tried:**

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device = nullptr;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> deviceContext = nullptr;
```

**Messages:**

```
Reason: cannot convert from 'ID3D11DeviceContext *' to 'DirectX::SpriteBatch'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous.
```

**EDIT, Complete Build Output:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Game, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory(2068,35): error C2664: 'DirectX::SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch(const DirectX::SpriteBatch &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'ID3D11DeviceContext *' to 'DirectX::SpriteBatch &&'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory(2067,59): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'ID3D11DeviceContext *' to 'DirectX::SpriteBatch'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory(2067,59): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>C:\Users\root\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Game\Game\include\SpriteBatch.h(90,9): message : see declaration of 'DirectX::SpriteBatch::SpriteBatch'
1>C:\Users\root\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Game\Game\main.cpp(199): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch,std::default_delete<DirectX::SpriteBatch>> std::make_unique<DirectX::SpriteBatch,ID3D11DeviceContext*&,0>(ID3D11DeviceContext *&)' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\memory(2068,35): error C2661: 'DirectX::SpriteFont::SpriteFont': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
1>C:\Users\root\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Game\Game\main.cpp(200): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteFont,std::default_delete<DirectX::SpriteFont>> std::make_unique<DirectX::SpriteFont,ID3D11Device*&,const wchar_t(&)[32],0>(ID3D11Device *&,const wchar_t (&)[32])' being compiled
1>Done building project "Game.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Want to show the initialization of these `device` and `deviceContext` variables in your question's code too? I'm not sure they'd be related to these specific error messages, but they are still important to getting this code working.

Comment: @DMGregory, I am using, `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` to initialize these two variables. **ID3D11Device** & **ID3D11DeviceContext**.

Comment: My best guess here is that the name `SpriteBatch` is resolving to a different type than the one documented at the link. Maybe a different version or something else entirely. It's difficult to verify this without a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example though. Can you please edit your question to contain the smallest example program that demonstrates this error?

Comment: I downloaded the latest stuff from their GitHub, and compiles with MSVS2019, then I copied the lib + includes and added them to my project, via settings. For the linking etc.

Comment: I appreciate the description, but that's not what I asked for. [Questions about debugging a problem in your project must contain a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) inside the question itself. As long as you have a single variable we can't see initialized, or a single header we can't see included, your example is not yet complete.

Comment: Also, please note that [cross-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795035/i-keep-getting-c2661-c2664-errors-without-any-indication-in-my-code) questions on stack exchange sites is not allowed. If the question on SO gets reopened, we'll have to close this one. Please select the site where you think you'll get the best/more answers and post only there.

Comment: Based on the line numbers, your included SpriteBatch.h doesn't seem to match what's in the GitHub repo, where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce issue was to try to use the *DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12* library but using the *DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11* instructions with a Direct3D 11 device/deviceContext.

IOW: You have the DirectX 12 version of the library added to your DirectX 11 project.

If you want Direct3D 11, be sure to use the instructions from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK#adding-to-a-vs-solution) for obtaining the correct version of the library.

Also make sure to follow the [tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).